# sed command using regular expressions to replace the major minor and release number

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am using Sed to replace the major, minor and release number in version.

In my case:

> version=10.2.0.1 (version=major.minor.release.buildnumber)

I don't want to change *buildnumber* in this version number. I only want to change the major, minor and release using `sed` command.

existing

```
version=10.20.0.1
```

I want the output as `version=11.21.2.1`
(Build number should not change (last part in my version ))

I used below command

```
sed -i -r s/version=(.*)/version=11.21.2/g <filename>
```

it giving the output as

```
version=11.21.2
```

which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

a compatible `sed` command would be:

```
$ sed 's/version=[1-9]\+[0-9]*\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/version=11.21.2/' <<<'version=10.20.0.1'
version=11.21.2.1
```

or with:

```
sed 's/version=[1-9]\+[0-9]*\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{2\}/version=11.21.2/' <<<'version=10.20.0.1'
```

or with:

```
sed -E 's/version=[1-9]+[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+){2}/version=11.21.2/' <<<'version=10.20.0.1'
```

or even like below if a version major_number also could start with 0 like minor and release parts:

```
sed -E 's/version=([0-9]+\.){3}/version=11.21.2./' <<<'version=10.20.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

We're having to make an assumption here, that the version string (a string, not a number) consist of four fields, delimited by a period. So, just trap the last one in the LHS of your regex.

I also recommend focusing on the line beginning `version=` first, and only touching the part after the `=` character. Put your regex in single quotes so the `\` escapes don't get preemptively escaped by the shell. Also, you don't need to use `(` and `)` around your match, because you're not keeping it for later.

```
sed -i -r '/version=/s/=.*\.[0-9][0-9]*$/version=11.21.2/g' <filename>
```

In the above, I'm allowing for the last field to be multiple numeric characters. You might want to put arbitrary characters in there, in which case:

```
sed  -r '/version=/s/=.*\.([^.]*)$/=11.21.2.\1/g' <filename>
```

To take an arbitrary change as input, say:

```
newver=11.21.2
sed  -r '/version=/s/=.*\.([^.]*)$/='${newver}'.\1/g' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect your command to know which part of the version string to replace? The `.*` will match the whole rest of the line, so everything gets replaced.

Now you can either define a pattern the matches just the three numbers you want to replace (that's what αғsнιη does in different ways in his answer) or preserve the buildnumber with a reference like here: `s/=.*(\..*)/=11.21.2\1/`. The `\.` matches a literal dot, so the last dot and everything after it can't get matched by the first `.*`. Thus, the buildnumber will match the `(\..*)`; putting it inside the `()` makes it accessible in the replacement as `\1`.

I add this answer because it seems easier to me than the regular expressions in the αғsнιη answer. Maybe a matter of taste.